# Date Format issue when going from English to French

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I currently are rendering a date using MVC as following:

```
<td class="tdAllotReq_DateTime">@csvAllotReq.SentDate</td>
```

and when viewing in a computer with english as it default language the following is being rendered:

```
<td class="tdAllotReq_DateTime">
    <label for="">13 May 15 11:15</label>
</td>
```

However when viewing in a computer with French as it's default language the following is being rendered:

```
<td class="tdAllotReq_DateTime">
    <label for="">15 11:15</label>
</td>
```

Can any one tell me why and how to force it to render the full date regardless of language?

Comment: specify the format in `ToString` method like `@csvAllotReq.SentDate.ToString("dd MMM yy hh:mm")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `csvAllotReq.SentDate` is a `DateTime`, you can format the date as follows

```
<td class="tdAllotReq_DateTime">@csvAllotReq.SentDate.ToString("dd MMM yy hh:mm")</td>
```